# Angular2: rxjs Subject in Angular2 child-parent component interaction

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, subject-observer

I want to manually subscribe to an event emitted by a directive, which, by design, should be available to multiple components of my application. At the moment the structure looks like this:

```
AppComponent
  Draggable.Directive (uses an attribute of a DOM element to control the behaviour)

  (and then, via routing)
  Parent1 Component
     Child1 Component
     Child2 Component
```

**app.module** looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, FooComponent, BarComponent, ParentComponent, DraggableDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Later in the development, another Parent component will be listening to draggable directive and implement its own logic.

None of the children component knows (or should care) about Draggable Directive doing anything to it. The parent component should. So, in **parent component**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DraggableDirective } from './draggable.directive';
import { FooComponent } from './foo.component';
import { BarComponent } from './bar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-view',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  providers: [DraggableDirective],
  moduleId: module.id
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('foo') fooC:FooComponent;
  @ViewChild('bar') barC:BarComponent;

  constructor(private draggable:DraggableDirective){
    draggable.droppedOn.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('listening', event);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   // updated
   // child view components
   this.fooC.fooInit();
  }
```

And here is the **directive**, using Subject and not EventEmitter, as recommended elsewhere:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Directive({
    selector: '[draggable], [data-draggable]'
})

export class DraggableDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    public droppedOn = new Subject();

    //... at some point this method is envoked
    couldDrop():void {

        if ( this.dElem ) {
            let _attr = this.dElem.dataset.indexed;
            console.log('emitting', _attr);
            this.droppedOn.next(_attr);

        }

    }
}
```

I get console logging "emitting" with the correct values. I never get "listening" from the parent component in the console. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The directive you create is not a service so it doesn't go to `@Component`'s `providers` array but into `declarations` instead. See for example https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html (you can add it to `NgModule` as well)

Also `ParentComponent` can't get an instance of a directive used somewhere in your template to its constructor. That's what `ViewChildren` is for. See for example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html

So in `ParentComponent` you subscribed to a different instance of `DraggableDirective` than your template is using.

Comment: Ok, so far so good. Should I then subscribe to the Subject() at a child component and forward it to the parent component?

Comment: @pop No, you use `@ViewChildren` annotation and `QueryList` which is Observable itself in the parent component to get updated list of all `DraggableDirective` directives. There you can access `droppedOn` property of each of them an subscribe to it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Comment: the problem I have, I guess, is that I use ViewChild variable to initialize the child component and cannot reuse it for observing changes with QueryList... What next? See upated parent component NgOnInit